# Does android have this function "How to filter based on spinner?"?

Tags: android, function, filter, spinner

I would like to ask a very general question.
" How to filter based on spinner?"
Meaning, there's few option in spinner ("education", "musuem", "restaurant")
Upon selecting "museum" it will show me a list of musuem.
Is there such a way to do it?
I've those data retrieved, just that, I would like to know whether spinner can do this function.

I've google it but doesn't seems to find the answer that I wanted
thus, would like to seek for advice whether is there any such sources.

CHANGES IN QUESTION, SOMEHOW SIMILAR

If I've this coding, and wanted to retrieve either "Museum", "Singapore", or "Centre",
How should I edit in my code?
Meaning, upon click on the selection in spinner,
it will change.

MainActivity.java
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
    String[] Category = {
    "Singapore discovery Centre",
    "Singapore Science Centre",
    "Mint Museum",
    "Singapore Art Museum",
    "Army Museum"
};

String [] keywords = {
    "Centre",
    "Musuem",
    "Singapore",

};

Spinner s1;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GridView
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Category)); 

                //SpinnerView
                s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, keywords);
                s1.setAdapter(adapter);
                s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have seleted item :" + keywords[index] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {}
                    });
                }


        public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + Category[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Use this `String Text = s1.getSelectedItem().toString()`.

Comment: HI, it ain't working..
Still the same =x

Comment: what is not working you need to get the item selected from spinner? put the code in the comment in `onItemSelected()`.

Comment: Actually what I wanted is.
for example : upon clicking "muesuem"
It will display all the musuem out that I've declared
(Singapore discovery Centre",
 "Singapore Science Centre",
 "Mint Museum",
 "Singapore Art Museum",
 "Army Museum")

Comment: you need to make filter for your listview items.

Comment: May I know how do i do so?
THat's the question that I would like to ask actually.
Cause I'm quite new to android, and currently working on a project.
I tried to google for sources but I couldn't find the question that I actually asking.

Comment: is it something like this?  if (Category.equals("centre")){
       
       
       
      }

Comment: something like this `String Text = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
          if(Text.endsWith("June"))
          {
           aa.getFilter().filter("Science Trail");
           aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }`. Also Declare `ArrayAdapter aa` as a class member `setListAdapter(aa)`

Comment: okay, sorry about that.

Comment: DO you mean like this?  String Text = s1.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
      if(Text.endsWith("musuem")) {
      s1.getFilter().filter("Mint Museum");
      s1.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I'm currently doing up the new question

Comment: @Raghunandan here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906874/how-to-filter-in-spinner-android

Comment: @Raghunandan could  you help me with this? I'm stuck. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917578/how-to-filter-by-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should `implement OnItemSelectedListener`.

```
Spinner sp;
    String[] strarr={"education", "musuem", "restaurant"};


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(filename.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,strarr);
        sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

you should override

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        int position =sp.getSelectedItemPosition();
              //things to do
}
and 
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        //things to do
    }
```

Comment: I've just edited my question, 
could you took a look and help me out with it?

Comment: can help me with this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917578/how-to-filter-by-listview

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a Listener named **OnItemSelectedListener** which tells you which item selected in the spinner so you can find the selected item id, then filter your adapter or whatever data structure you have with that selected Item.

```
Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
        })
});
```

Comment: Hmm okay thanks.
Even if I'm retrieving the live data, also possible?

Comment: yes,its the way you can find which item selected in your spinner , so you can fetch your live data according to your spinner selected item , another thing pls check answer mark in your questions which helped you solve your issues!its a motivation for others to help you