# Why isn't my listview working, android

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to do a simple coding for spinner and list,
 which is just to show the data.
However, I got no idea,
why the data that I written for list view, isn't display.
Could anyone help me out with this?

here is my coding.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] Category = {
    "Science Trail",
    "Megabug Return"

};

String [] months = {
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "Septemeber",
    "November",
    "December",


};

Spinner s1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GridView
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Category)); 

        //SpinnerView
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, months);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have seleted item :" + months[index] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {}
            });
        }


        private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


        public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id)
        {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + Category[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/android:list"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
     android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

                    </ListView>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: extend `ListActivity`.

Comment: Thanks.Hi, it still don't show

Comment: u hv not setted data itself so its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Activity must extend `ListActivity`.

Use the below

```
      public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] Category = {
    "Science Trail",
    "Megabug Return"

};

String [] months = {
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "Septemeber",
    "November",
    "December",


};

Spinner s1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GridView
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Category)); 

        //SpinnerView
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, months);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have seleted item :" + months[index] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {}
            });
        }


}
```

Remove this

```
     private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {

     }
```

`public void setListAdapter (ListAdapter adapter)` // method of ListActivity

Added in API level 1

Provide the cursor for the list view.

More info @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Snap shot on my device

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot!(:

Sorry to bother, do you have any idea on this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906019/does-android-have-this-function-how-to-filter-based-on-spinner/17906211?noredirect=1#17906211

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things.

1. Extend ListActivity instead of Activity.
2. Delete method setListAdapter.

Comment: @user1929520 `setListAdapter` is a method of `ListActivity. so you should extend `ListActivity` instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

your setListAdapter method is empty...
you have 2 options.
1. add a ListView to your layout and use the findViewById to init the list view's adapter.
2. as Raghunandan mentioned, extend ListActivity and call the setListAdapter of the ListActivity, not your custom and empty one.