# How to filter by listview

Tags: listview, filter, spinner

I would like to filter into listview based on Spinner.

For example, I've a code for ListView which is

```
("Singapore Discovery Centre",
"Singapore Science Centre",
"Mint Museum",
"Singapore Art Museum",
"Army Museum").
```

I've a code for Spinner which is

```
("Centre", 
"Singapore",
"Museum").
```

What I would like to have is: Upon clicking Singapore, in the listview, it will filter out all the "Singapore"

```
("Singapore Discovery Centre",
"Singapore Science Centre",
"Singapore Art Museum" ).
```

I tried out this coding of mine,

Could you be guide me, what is wrong with it?

MainActivity.java

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] Category = {
    "Singapore discovery Centre",
    "Singapore Science Centre",
    "Mint Museum",
    "Singapore Art Museum",
    "Army Museum"
};

String [] keywords = {
    "Centre",
    "Musuem",
    "Singapore",

};

Spinner s1;
ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Category)); 

                ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, keywords);

                aa.setDropDownViewResource(
                           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        s1.setAdapter(aa);
                    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        listview.setFilterText(Category[position]);
    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        listview.setFilterText("");
    }

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + Category[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
```

Logcat:

```
  07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spinnertest/com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1024)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
    07-29 14:43:30.429: E/AndroidRuntime(30599):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: why do you have `abstract` remove it. just have `public class MainActivity`

Comment: If I don't put, there will be an error

Comment: what is the error if you don't use abstract.

Comment: The MainActivity will be hightlighted

Comment: highlighted is useless word specify the error pls. i just tried i get no error

Comment: beginning, it is highlighted, but I  not sure why it is not now.
I tried to run it but errors occurs

Comment: i get NullPointerException when i run.

Comment: I would like to check on this
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        listview.setFilterText(Category[position]);
    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        listview.setFilterText("");
    }

Comment: I not sure what is wrong with my code,
but it doesn't work out when I try to filter

Comment: you should use a custom listview and use a custom filter.

Comment: okay, thanks..
I would like to ask, is ther any tutorial that I could follow after? I tried to google but can't find any

Comment: i just made a sample using your data. i will post it. modify the same according to your needs.

Comment: posted the snap shots also. check the post. if it helps don't forget to accept and upvote.

Comment: If I were to change to to retrieve from some XML data, just to check with you, is it just edit the code and put the XML code data in it and remove this "
    String[] Category = { "Singapore discovery Centre",
            "Singapore Science Centre", "Mint Museum", "Singapore Art Museum",
            "Army Museum" };"  ??

Comment: you can get you data from internet or form xml or from json. it will work. make sure it is of type string.

Comment: I will be getting the data from xml..
Could you help me check the code after I have coded it out? thanks in advance

Comment: post it as a new question with the relevant details i am sure the community will help you. i will see if i can help if i am on line.

Comment: hey, may I know exactly which part do you use in the code to filter out the keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a custom Adapter and a custom filter.

Remove the `abstract` for you class.

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] Category = { "Singapore discovery Centre",
            "Singapore Science Centre", "Mint Museum", "Singapore Art Museum",
            "Army Museum" };

    String[] keywords = { "Centre", "Museum", "Singapore",

    };
    ArrayList<String> cat = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mPostingData = new ArrayList<String>();
    Spinner s1;
    ListView listview;
    CustomAdapter cus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        for (int i = 0; i < Category.length; i++) {
            cat.add(Category[i]);
        }

        // aa = new
        // ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Category);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mPostingData = cat;
        for (int i = 0; i < mPostingData.size(); i++) {
            if (mPostingData.size() > 0)
                Log.i("Datas", mPostingData.get(i));
        }
        cus = new CustomAdapter(this, 0);
        setListAdapter(cus);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, keywords);

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(aa);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        // listview.setFilterText(Category[position]);
        String Text = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cus.getFilter().filter(Text);
        cus.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // listview.setFilterText("");
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + mPostingData.get(position),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public void setData(ArrayList<String> mPpst) {
            mPostingData = mPpst;// contains class items data.
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count >= 0) {
                        setData((ArrayList<String>) results.values);
                    } else {
                        setData(cat);// set original values
                    }

                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                        constraint = constraint.toString();
                        ArrayList<String> foundItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                        if (cat != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < cat.size(); i++) {

                                if (cat.get(i).contains(constraint)) {
                                    System.out.println("My datas" + cat.get(i));
                                    foundItems.add(cat.get(i));

                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        result.count = foundItems.size();// search results found
                                                            // return count
                        result.values = foundItems;// return values
                    } else {
                        result.count = -1;// no search results found
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            };
        }

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mPostingData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder vh;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                vh.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                convertView.setTag(vh);
            } else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if (mPostingData.size() > 0)
                vh.t1.setText(mPostingData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView t1;
    }
}
```

Emulator snap shots

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls get to  know about custom filters. check the filter method.

Comment: so the filter method is the place where you do filtering upon getting the keywords out? pardon me for the question, I'm new to android, and in the learning mode too.

Comment: yes. but you should get to know what's hapenning. try it out on your own. but i can't comment on each and every line.

Comment: all right, thanks. I shall go continue and read it. I'm stuck somewhere, thus I'm asking..
Sorry about it

Comment: Sorry, may i know what is mPostingData ??

Comment: @user1929520 this is my last comment. i can't keep commenting. mPostingData is a arraylist one for the original data when nothing matches mPostingData contains the filtered data. pls don't ask for clarification on each and everything in the comment section. If ou have doubts pls post it as a new question with relevant details. thank you.

Comment: could you help me with this?
This will be the last time I'm asking you.. I promise.
Sorry about it